# How to pass the input file name to an awk script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have written a simple **awk** command inside a file named as ***code.sh*** **to find all the even numbers from the input file** named as ***test*** and **sort them numerically and display them on the command line**

The input file ***test*** is

```
23
34
45
56
6
76
5
43
22
45
67
445
55
33
44
44
88
76
54
0
9
8
7
66
```

The code is written in ***code.sh*** is shown below

```
awk '
    BEGIN{
    }
    {
        if($1 % 2 == 0){
            print($1);
        }
    }
    END{
    }
' test | sort -n
```

In the command prompt I am executing the below code to run the script

```
./code.sh
```

The above code works perfectly fine and I am getting the expected output.

**But in the code I am providing the name of the input file (in this case input file named ***test***) inside the code.**

**But what I want is to provide the input file name in the command line.**

And I think this is one of the solution.

```
BEGIN{
}
{
    if($1 % 2 == 0){
        print($1);
    }
}
END{
}
```

And in command line the code that I execute to perform the task is

```
awk -f code.sh test | sort -n
```

But in this case I have to write the **sort command** outside the script, in the command line. But I want to write all the code (the awk command to only select the even numbers and sort command using pipe | to sort the output of awk script) inside the ***code.sh*** file and provide the input file ***test*** in the command line argument.

***IN HackerRank I HAVE EXECUTED THE BELOW CODE WHICH IS ACTUALLY MY REQUIREMENT AND, USED THE CUSTOM INPUT AND RUN THE SCRIPT, AND I AM GETTING THE EXPECTED OUTPUT. BUT I DON'T KNOW WHAT COMMAND THE HackerRank PLATFORM IS USING TO RUN THE SCRIPT***

```
awk '
BEGIN{
}
{
    if($1 % 2 == 0){
        print($1);
    }
}
END{
} ' | sort -n
```

Now I want to execute the above script with providing the input file ***test*** in the command line in my own machine.

This command I tried which failed

```
./code.sh test
```

Comment: Sounds like you should tag your question with "hackerrank" if such a tag exists or post your question on a forum about "hackerrank" or contact whoever supports whatever that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in `code.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk '
    script
' "${@:--}" | sort
```

The `"${@:--}"` syntax is so it'll read input from a file or a pipe. Obviously replace `script` with your actual awk script.

Answer (score 3):

You should make use of `$1` in your script and make sure you pass it to `awk` script as Input_file. Something like following should do the trick(because of lack of expected output samples didn't test it).

***Fixes in OP's code:***

- Also as an improvement I have removed `BEGIN` and `END` sections from OP's code since there were nothing happening in those section of OP's code.
- Then to find the even lines one should use `FNR%2==0` condition, where `FNR` represents the current line number.

---

```
cat script.ksh
val=$1
awk '
{
  if(FNR % 2 == 0){
    print($1);
  }
}
' "$val" | sort -n
```

Following is how one should run it:

```
./script.ksh Input_file
```

***NOTE:*** You could also add a `usage` option to above script(which tells people in case they forget to pass any variable they should know how it actually runs), leaving it as an excessive for OP here.

Comment: or allow for multiple file inputs with `awk '....' $@ | sort -n`. Good luck to all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221054/discussion-between-amit-kumar-mahapatra-and-ravindersingh13).

Answer (score 1):

If you use GNU awk, you don't need `sort`:

```
# evens.awk
$1 % 2 == 0 {evens[NR] = $1}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
    for (i in evens)
        print evens[i]
}
```

then

```sh
gawk -f evens.awk test
```

The line `PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"` instructs awk to sort the array numerically by the array values while iterating with `for`.

Refs:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Array-Traversal.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html

Answer (score 1):

you can embed sorting in the `awk` script as well

```
awk '!($1%2){print | "sort -n"}' "$1"
```